# Bound on the amount of probability mass 'seen' from a sample.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, terminology, concentration-of-measure

I was thinking of the following puzzle out of the blue and I would like to know if it has already been studied (I would assume so due to the simplicity of the setup). Imagine you have some unknown discrete random variable $X$ with a support over $v_1,...,v_k$, you draw an i.i.d sample $S$ consisting of $X_1,...,X_m$; you would like to lower bound the amount of probability mass 'seen' (which we will denote by $L_{S}$) in your sample. Formally, $L_S = \mathbb{P}(\cup_{i=1}^m\{X = X_i\}) = \sum_{i\in [k]}\mathbb{P}(X=v_i)\mathbb{1}_{v_i \in S}$

E.G. imagine $X_i \sim \text{Bern}(p)$ then there are 3 cases for $m\geq 1$

1. $X_i = 1 \ \forall i \in [m] \implies L_S = p\ $ (since $\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = p$)
2. $X_i = 0 \ \forall i \in [m] \implies L_S = 1-p\ $ ($\mathbb{P}(X = 0) = 1-p$)
3. $\exists i, j \in [m] : X_i = 0 \text{ and } X_j = 1 \implies L_S = 1\ $ ($\mathbb{P}(X = 1 \cup X = 0) = 1$)

We can calculate the probability of every such case without much effort and then derive a simple bound through markov's inequality that shows:
$$
\mathbb{P}_{S\sim X^m}(L_S \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[L_S]}{\epsilon}
$$

I would like to know the name of such a quantity, if it has been studied before, and in what contexts. I would ultimately like a PAC-style (not necessarily distribution-independent) bound of the form
$$
\mathbb{P}(L_S\geq \epsilon) \geq 1-\delta
$$
where the constants depend on $k$ and $m$

Comment: If $p(i)=P[X=v_i]$ for $i \in \{1, ..., k\}$, you can say $P[1-L\geq \delta] \leq \frac{E[1-L]}{\delta}$ where $E[1-L]=\sum_{i=1}^kp(i)(1-p(i))^m$ and so $$P[1-L<\delta] \geq 1 - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^kp(i)(1-p(i))^m}{\delta}$$ which gives a lower bound on $P[L>1-\delta]$ for any $\delta>0$. And of course $P[L\geq p_{min}]=1$ where $p_{min} = \min_{i\in\{1, ..., k\}} \{p(i)\}$.